# document.write with img src

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, document.write

```
 document.write("<img src='" + imgNumber + ".png' alt="' /> ") ;
```

I get a syntax error with this code.

"Insert a command that writes this text img src='imgNumber.png' alt='' />
where *imgNumber* is the value of the imgNumber variable."

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Comment: uncaught syntax error:unexpected token illegal

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read about [Javascript strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp), you got a syntax error because of the double quotes following `alt="`, you need to either escape them or use separate strings and concatenate them (all in the  reference link)